# How to disallow update command to look for google-chrome dependency

Tags: linux, google-chrome, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I am using ubuntu 12.04. I am trying to update the system but getting some error with google-chrome module.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Is there any way, I can remove above dependency so that my update could run successfully, I tried by removing google chrome using:

```
sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
```

but error remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can comment your update link for google chrome in the apt source list file.

1. `cd /etc/apt`
2. `sudo grep -rn "google" *` to find out the apt list file which includes the update link of google chrome
3. Use one of your familiar editor to mark those lines.

In my case, the messages are as followed,

> sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3:deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
>   sources.list.d/google-chrome.list.save:3:deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main